# ExtJS exclude column in a grid from any hiding/showing logic

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 5.0 and am working on a grid where two columns (let's call them *newColumns*) have a `hidden` attribute set initially through a `beforerender` listener from the grid. They can have `hidden: true` or `hidden: false` depending on some external variable. I want to exclude these columns from any other hiding/showing logic that applies later: there is unfortunately logic for hiding/showing OTHER columns that kicks in depending on certain filters and overrides the initial `hidden` attribute of the two *newColumns*.

Is there a method/attribute/property in ExtJS 5.0 that prevents the hiding/showing of these two columns? I know there is `hideable: false` that can make the columns unable to be hidden, but is there also `showable: false` or an equivalent that prevents the columns from being hidden after that?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO 'hideable' removes the column from hide/show column menu. Why don't you use 'hidden' with 'hideable' properties? Something like this:

```
{
    text: 'First Name',
    dataIndex: 'firstname',
    hideable: false,
    hidden: true // User will not be able to show this column. Or set false, then user will not be able to hide it. 
}
```